# How to use Serilog with Unity in appsettings

Tags: c#, web-config, unity-container, serilog

I would like to define with Unity framework inside the web.config using `<constructor>` tag, the equivalent of executing this code:

```
    ILogger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                    .CreateLogger();
```

but inside the web.config.. something like this:

```
    <type type="ILogger" name="serilog" mapTo="Serilog, Serilog.Logging">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
            <constructor>
                ///read from appsettings.
            </constructor>
        </typeConfig>
    </type>
```

and then

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
</appSettings>
```

I cannot find any example for calling the sink methods with unity inside a web.config.
Can any body help me?